# C# looking through folders and subfolders for the list of images and copy them to new folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, copy, streamreader

I wrote this program in C# that moves the images from one folder to another based on `list.txt` file in which i specify the image names. Now the code below works perfectly fine but what i need to do is to somehow make to look in to the folder and sub-folders for the images on that `list` and then once they are found copy them to single folder. I was trying to use `Directory.GetFiles` to list the images in that directory and than once they are matched to be copied in the new folder but I am having trouble figuring out how to do it.

Any advice ?

```
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;

    namespace ImageManager
    {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //-----------Copy Files In The List-------------------//

        private void CopyFileInList()
        {

            var source = tbSource.Text;
            var destination = tbDestination.Text;
            var itemList = tbList.Text + @"\List.txt";

            try
            {
                StreamReader sr;
                string curFile;
                string to_file, from_file;

                sr = File.OpenText(itemList);
                curFile = sr.ReadLine();
                while (curFile != null)
                {
                    to_file = destination + "/" + curFile;
                    from_file = source + "/" + curFile;
                    FileSystem.CopyFile(from_file, to_file, UIOption.AllDialogs);
                    curFile = sr.ReadLine();
                }
                sr.Close();
                MessageBox.Show(@"The Images were copied", @"HDS Image Manager",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
            }
            catch (DirectoryNotFoundException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please specify source path, destination path and List file location.");
            }

        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           CopyFileInList();
        }
        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void folderBrowserDialog1_HelpRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void DestinationPath_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                tbDestination.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
            }
        }
        private void SourcePath_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                tbSource.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
            }
        }
        private void ListPath_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                tbList.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Could Not fined the List.txt file");
            }
        }
        private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        private void tbList_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

vesan - i tried to use what you suggested

```
 StreamReader sr;
 string curFile;
 string to_file;
 string [] from_file;

 sr = File.OpenText(itemList);
 curFile = sr.ReadLine();
 while (curFile != null)
 {
       to_file = destination + "/" + curFile;
       from_file = Directory.GetFiles(source, curFile, System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
       File.Copy(from_file, to_file, UIOption.AllDialogs);
       curFile = sr.ReadLine();
 }
```

and I'm getting small error that i can not convert `string[]` to `string` at line `file.copy(from_file)` 
If i don't declare `from_file` as `string[]` i am getting other issues. Then, How do i fix this?

Comment: Maybe not the best performance-wise, but have you tried calling `Directory.GetFiles(source, curFile, SearchOption.AllDirectories)`? That should look through all subdirectories for your file.

Comment: Also, I'd probably just use `System.IO.File.Copy` method to copy the files: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: vesan - thank you for your quick response. please see my edited post with the code you suggested.

Comment: If you are giving 'curFile' exact full name, check 'from_File' contains value (I assume it contains only 1 value if file found) and use it. File.Copy(from_file[0],...

Comment: Rajesh -  thank you. This fixed the error however when i execute the program i get this error: "System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'". There should be one single instance of the file i am looking in the folder/subfolder

Comment: Try doing `from_file.FirstOrDefault()` - if it returns null, it means file was found, if it returns a valid string, that should be the file path. Any other issues, try going through it with a debugger and see what exactly is going on.